# creating a maskbit based on the number of user count with IPAddress using python

Tags: python, networking, ip-address, subnet

can we create code in Python that can accept the Number of users as an input and creates an Subnetted IP with the Mask bit for an example 10.141.0.0/13 is an  ip I want to  add 125 users  from this IP so I have to Subnet this(10.141.0.0./13) to (10.141.0.0/25) , can we create a script in Python to do this? I have a clue we can do something with the python module 'netaddr', But suggest me something to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Slightly longer answer: determine the smallest power of two minus two that is larger or equal than your node number. Calculate 32 - power for the mask size. The host mask is (2^power)-1, the network mask (2^32)-1 - host mask.

Comment: can u please give an example.for the above concept

Comment: Start with 56 hosts. 56+2=58. Smallest power of two larger than that: 64. log2(64) = 6. 32-6 = 26, so it's a /26 subnet. The host mask is (2^6)-1. The network mask is ((2^32)-1) - ((2^6)-1).